# How to get rid of array keyword in a python array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Somewhere in my code where I am multiplying two arrays, the result has the keyword `array` which I cannot perform any more operation on that. What does this keyword mean? And what is the right way to resolve the error?

```
L,Y,AL = 2 ,[[1 0]] ,[[ 1.78862847  0.43650985]]
arr = - (np.divide(Y, AL) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - AL))
>>>((array([[ 0.09649747, -1.8634927 ],
           [-0.2773882 , -0.35475898],
           [-0.08274148, -0.62700068],
           [-0.04381817, -0.47721803]]), 
     array([[-1.31386475,  0.88462238,  0.88131804,  1.70957306],
           [ 0.05003364, -0.40467741, -0.54535995, -1.54647732],
           [ 0.98236743, -1.10106763, -1.18504653, -0.2056499 ]]), 
     array([[ 1.48614836],
           [ 0.23671627],
           [-1.02378514]])), 
     array([[-0.7129932 ,  0.62524497],
           [-0.16051336, -0.76883635],
           [-0.23003072,  0.74505627]]))
```

Comment: Can you update with the code that generated this output?

Comment: The problem is likely not that `array` "keyword" you see but the fact that you have tuples of arrays.

Comment: im new to py. here is the update

Comment: I don't think this is the code that produced the result.

Comment: why negative votes ? my numeric results are correct, I debuged everything up the previous line. only I get error when I pass the result to create a sigmoid activation function and it throws err.

Comment: Unfortunately we get a lot of questions from people working with these 'deep-learning' tutorials. 'sklearn', 'keras' and 'tensorflow' also generate these questions.  The code can generate complex arrays and data structures.  Apparently the tutorials don't expect a good grounding in Python or `numpy`, so when users step outside the bounds of the tutorial they get lost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+coursera - example search on numpy and coursera.

Comment: It is understandable. thanks for support.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the result into a list. Example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
np.add(a,b)
```

This returns array([5, 7, 9]). But,

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
list(np.add(a,b))
```

returns,

[5, 7, 9].

However, it is unlikely that you are facing errors because of the presence of the array keyword. It is just a representation. Check your tuple sizes and dimensions because that is where the fault usually lies.

Comment: values are correct, it seems when I am vectorizing the parameters to calculate the sigmoid function, it doesnt accept this form of input. so far i havenot had problem but this part is throwing err.

Comment: See its shape. If it's of form (n, 1) reshape it to (n,) and vice versa and then feed it as input.

Comment: no actually i have to keep the shape to n,1. losing the second dimention creates bug all over the application.

Answer (score 1):

I did a copy-n-paste and got a prettier display:

```
((array([[ 0.09649747, -1.8634927 ],
         [-0.2773882 , -0.35475898],
         [-0.08274148, -0.62700068],
         [-0.04381817, -0.47721803]]),
  array([[-1.31386475,  0.88462238,  0.88131804,  1.70957306],
         [ 0.05003364, -0.40467741, -0.54535995, -1.54647732],
         [ 0.98236743, -1.10106763, -1.18504653, -0.2056499 ]]),
  array([[ 1.48614836],
         [ 0.23671627],
         [-1.02378514]])),
 array([[-0.7129932 ,  0.62524497],
        [-0.16051336, -0.76883635],
        [-0.23003072,  0.74505627]]))
```

You have a tuple of  4 arrays.  They differ in shape, (4,2), (3,4), (3,1), and a (3,2).

Looking more carefully at the ().  It's a 2 element tuple.  One element is also a tuple, with 3 array.  The 2nd is an array.

Tell us about `Y` and `AL`; in particular what are they? tuples? tuples of arrays? object dtype arrays?  It's hard to imagine objects that could be acted on by `np.divide` that would produce this tuple.

---

With your added values (I had to add `,`)

```
In [63]: L,Y,AL = 2, [[1, 0]], [[ 1.78862847,  0.43650985]]
In [64]: - (np.divide(Y, AL) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - AL))
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

creating arrays from the lists:

```
In [65]: Y=np.array(Y); AL = np.array(AL)
In [66]: - (np.divide(Y, AL) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - AL))
Out[66]: array([[-0.5590876 ,  1.77465391]])
```

The result is (1,2) array, and looks nothing like your `arr`.

---

Sometimes posters get arrays containing arrays.  Constructing from scratch can be tricky:

```
In [105]: np.array(arr)
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (3)
```

This is the kind of error I get when I try to apply numpy functions to this nested tuple.

A more reliable way of creating an object array is:

```
In [106]: A = np.empty(2, object)
In [107]: A[:] = arr
In [108]: A
Out[108]: 
array([ (array([[ 0.09649747, -1.8634927 ],
       [-0.2773882 , -0.35475898],
       [-0.08274148, -0.62700068],
       [-0.04381817, -0.47721803]]), array([[-1.31386475,  0.88462238,  0.88131804,  1.70957306],
       [ 0.05003364, -0.40467741, -0.54535995, -1.54647732],
       [ 0.98236743, -1.10106763, -1.18504653, -0.2056499 ]]), array([[ 1.48614836],
       [ 0.23671627],
       [-1.02378514]])),
       array([[-0.7129932 ,  0.62524497],
       [-0.16051336, -0.76883635],
       [-0.23003072,  0.74505627]])], dtype=object)
```

and turning the inner tuple into an array as well:

```
In [109]: A[0] = np.array(A[0])
In [110]: A
Out[110]: 
array([ array([ array([[ 0.09649747, -1.8634927 ],
       [-0.2773882 , -0.35475898],
       [-0.08274148, -0.62700068],
       [-0.04381817, -0.47721803]]),
       array([[-1.31386475,  0.88462238,  0.88131804,  1.70957306],
       [ 0.05003364, -0.40467741, -0.54535995, -1.54647732],
       [ 0.98236743, -1.10106763, -1.18504653, -0.2056499 ]]),
       array([[ 1.48614836],
       [ 0.23671627],
       [-1.02378514]])], dtype=object),
       array([[-0.7129932 ,  0.62524497],
       [-0.16051336, -0.76883635],
       [-0.23003072,  0.74505627]])], dtype=object)
```

The `print` (str as opposed to repr representation) may be different:

```
In [111]: print(A)
[ array([ array([[ 0.09649747, -1.8634927 ],
       [-0.2773882 , -0.35475898],
       [-0.08274148, -0.62700068],
       [-0.04381817, -0.47721803]]),
       array([[-1.31386475,  0.88462238,  0.88131804,  1.70957306],
       [ 0.05003364, -0.40467741, -0.54535995, -1.54647732],
       [ 0.98236743, -1.10106763, -1.18504653, -0.2056499 ]]),
       array([[ 1.48614836],
       [ 0.23671627],
       [-1.02378514]])], dtype=object)
 array([[-0.7129932 ,  0.62524497],
       [-0.16051336, -0.76883635],
       [-0.23003072,  0.74505627]])]
```

The fact that your sample has the `()` markings strongly suggests it's tuples, not list or object array.

Sometimes lists or tuples of arrays can be turned into a 'flatter' array with some version of `concatenate` (hstack, vstack, stack), but that's not the case here.

Comment: @lsma, I know what I am doing here. The OP is confused about what he's seeing, thinking that `array` is an extraneous keyword, instead of an important clue as to the structure. What I showed is too long to put a comment. Also comments don't preserve formating. Lets focus on helping, rather than picky differences between comments and answers..

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for helping. let me double check and provide more code when I get home. I understood that these are only different representations but proceeding from that point got annoying. not sure why people giving negative vote when they cannot help...

Comment: @DragonKnight, I exapanded on what an object dtype array would look like.

Comment: I cannot add datatype to the results. I dont remember if it was from backward or forward propagation results.